# Saving in SD card

Tags: sd-card

I have selected SD card as preselected storage space, but only the photographs I take are being stored in SD. Any other files, like Viber or Snapchat photographs, are being stored in phone's memory. How to solve tha?

Phone: ZTE Blade S6 Flex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how it works. Storage of things depends on app and it's developer. Almost all the social and messenger apps save their work in internal memory including photos and related media. You can not change this due to several restrictions put by original creators of Android (I'm talking about Google). Original OEM manufacturers are trying to embed as much internal memory as they can due to these restrictions. In my anticipation there will be no expandable storage options in future.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Android 6.0 and up you have two ways to setup your SD (expandable storage). One as a standalone secondary storage. default on your device. This allows you to use it just for storing data, you can not typically operate from it. Far as what is defaulting to save on your SD can all change in stock Android and even more when rooted. You can load as many apk's as you want to it, but they will not operate. This is good for backups and uninstalling apks you might want later. You can route a lot of your partitions files to it in a mirror format, ie downloads, recovery. But your device sees your SD as removable so nothing that would break your OS will not store there.

The second way which is cool. You can Merge your SD with the OS. Before the merge, you have two partitions. One basically for OS, secoundROM and Recovery a second for the file system. Once you merge your SD with your system, it becomes part of your system. (downside it can not be removed) So if you have a 16gb ROM and 16gb SD, now you have 32gb storage. The first two partitions on ROM and the SD has six (the six is confusing, sry), but you now have 8 and everything is spread out, for the most part. That part should not matter because it is no longer removable.

How 2 Video
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8h94v8G9nxA